# How do I represent a custom GCP machine type in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to launch a new GCP server using Terraform. But I don't know how to represent a custom machine type in Terraform.

In dev we have a machine type set to this:

```
machine_type = "n1-highmem-8"
```

But in production we have a custom machine type according to the GCP console:

```
Machine type
custom (16 vCPUs, 90 GB memory)
```

How can I put a custom machine type like this into a Terraform config?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs it should be: `machine_type = "custom-16-92160"`. That's for 16 CPUs and 90 GB of ram.